# Celery like system based on django channels

Tags: python, django

According to the docs of django channels:

http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts.html?highlight=celery#next-steps

> One thing channels do not do, however, is guarantee delivery. If you need certainty that tasks will complete, use a system designed for this with retries and persistence (e.g. Celery), or alternatively make a management command that checks for completion and re-submits a message to the channel if nothing is completed (rolling your own retry logic, essentially).

I worked with celery some years ago. Yes, it is great, it is big, it is too much. I would like to avoid it.

I am searching a simple tasks queue with guarantee delivery and a re-submission on failure.

An other alternative would be [python-rq](http://python-rq.org/). But this has other disadvantages like using pickle data format instead of json.

Answer (score 0):

A friend gave me an advice:

https://github.com/furious-luke/django-cq

Looks good.

From the docs

> An attempt to implement a distributed task queue for use with Django channels. Modelled after RQ and Celery, complex task workflows are possible, all leveraging the Channels machinery.

Comment: I am thinking about replacing Celery in a project I am working on because of a lot of instability I am facing. Do you think django-cq is worth it and production ready ?

Comment: @thelinuxer I only tried it once. I have no real world and long-term experience with it. Sorry.